# Previously posted question appears when "Ask Question" clicked

Tags: support

I was trying to ask a question and when I clicked Ask Question the contents were filled with my previously asked question (from days ago) and only when I "posted" the question (which I assume is now a duplicate) then the "ask question" functionality became available.

Then I tried to ask my new question and got the "hang on there tiger, only one question every 20 minutes..." which I know is not an error but by design.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have some configuration problems with your browsers.

We save a draft of one (1) answer and one (1) question (per user, per site) as they are being composed -- this is done by sending them to the server as you type. You had a draft question saved.

Drafts are cleared when you post a question or answer.

You can reproduce this trivially by clicking ask, typing some stuff, waiting 45 seconds, then closing the browser window. When you reopen the browser window and navigate back to the ask page you'll find your draft there. That's because it is saved on our servers.

If you don't like what is there, use the delete key to delete it and replace it with different text.. not sure why you felt you had to post it.

Comment: My guess is that I tried to ask a question with one browser and was having problems and so probably switched to another browser and copy/pasted the question and that's what happened. I assume if I had cleared my cookies that would have resolved the "hanging around" question.